# JVM is stuck trying to acquire a semaphore

Tags: java, windows, jvm, jetty, semaphore

I have an application using embedded Jetty (version 9.3.6.v20151106) and JDK 8u65.

When I use this application on Mac or Linux, I have no difficulties. On Windows however, Jetty does not start and the application hangs permanently.

I ran a jstack command on the process and isolated the thread which is holding up the startup of the server.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x1a3b2018> (a java.util.concurrent.Semaphore$NonfairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1336)
```

I looked for another thread holding up the lock, but there were none.

How do I debug this issue further? Is it a JVM bug, or a Windows security feature? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce with a single Java program, but it doesn't behave the same way. I also could see that the number of cores returned by Windows is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was blind to my own logs. I found out that I was throwing OOMs while scanning jars of the application.
There are a number of factors as to why this happens specifically on Windows. First off, this is a 32 bit distrib, so it's a little capricious when it comes to memory. The max heap size for Java ends up being affected by the way.

As discussed on the #jetty IRC channel (credits and kudos to joakime for his awesome help), this is due to the jar scanning of the WEB-INF/lib of the application. This bloats startup time and may result in OOMs if you have large jars full of junk files.

joakime pointed out two possibilities to solve the issue:

- Prepackage and prepare the app more and use [quickstart](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html).
- Scan jars deliberately by using a regexp to choose which ones to scan (bottom of this [page](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-webapps.html))

I ended up using the latter. I use this regexp to match the jstl jar and the spring jars (I use the taglibs jar of spring security):

```
".*/jstl-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/spring-[^/]*\\.jar$"
```

Comment: with spring in the mix, don't forget that you can capture all logging frameworks and route them into a single logging layer using slf4j.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that windows does not report the number of processors correctly.
Try setting org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.multiThreaded property to false, see if that helps.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't seem to take. I'll keep trying (from command line with java -jar). I'll update the question with more info as I try to narrow things down.

Answer (score 0):

> I looked for another thread holding up the lock, but there were none.

A semaphore is more general than a lock. It's a pile of permits not necessarily associated with any thinig at all. They can be acquired and released by one or more threads and releases are not required to occur on the thread that have done the acquire.

A thread could even create a semaphore, consume all available permits and then wait for its own semaphore without another thread ever touching it.

Therefore debugging semaphores cannot be easily done by looking for other threads "holding a lock".

To debug them you have to trace acquires and releases and see where permits are drained and then figure out where they should be released but aren't.